# R (dplyr tidyverse) correlation matrix error: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, correlation

I want to create a correlation matrix for several variables in a DataFrame in R-Tidyverse by: `correlations <- cor(DataFrame)`

However, I get this error:

> "'x' must be numeric" .
> How to resolve this?

Comment: You may have non-numeric columns try `cor(Filter(is.numeric, DataFrame))`

Answer (score 2):

In case you have numeric data with class `class` character you could do as an alternative this:

```
library(dplyr)
correlations <- cor(DataFrame %>% type.convert(as.is=TRUE))
```

Comment: I have numbers but I guess they are not of the numeric type. This gave me an 'must be numeric' error. How can I turn the values into numbers? Thanks

Comment: It should work with the above code using `type.convert`